# How to get Taxonomy field value list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs, taxonomyfieldvalue

I have a list with multiple Taxonomy fields (Gender, Region, etc). 
I'm doing a simple form using Angular to add new items to this list.
I'm using the SP Rest API to get and post the information but I can't find a way to get the list of possible values for this Managed fields in order to populate a couple of comboboxes.

Regards.

Comment: it's currently not possible to get taxonomy data via rest api. You should use the JS objects instead. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj857114.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to get multiple Taxonomy field value, loop the data.d.results and data.d.results.meta.result

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
TestFunc();
function TestFunc()
{

$.ajax({
    url: "http://sp/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Demolist')/items?$select=meta",

    type: "GET",

    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      },

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data.d.results);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) 
    {

           for(var j=0; j<data.d.results[i].meta.results.length;j++)
          {
               console.log(data.d.results[i].meta.results[j].Label);
          }

    }

    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error')
    }
});

}


</script>
```

This is the returned data.d.results, for "meta" field, it will has two row in results array:
[image]